# If a subset $E$ of $R^n$ is bounded then E is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove the above proposition. The book that I am looking at contains E in a cube of the form T=[−b,b]×⋯×[−b,b] for some large b>0. Then, since any subspace of a totally bounded metric space is totally bounded, it suffices to show that T is totally bounded. For this, let e>0. **Then the balls B(ej;e) cover T, where j=(j1,...,jn) ranges over all integral lattice points of Rn which satisfy e|ji|≤2b, where i ranges from 1 to n.** Since there are only finitely many such lattice points, T is totally bounded.

I don't understand the bold part of the proof. I guess they created an arbitrary e-ball by putting the center of the ball as the scalar multiplication of j by e. But then I don't see how the restiction of lattice points which satisfy, e|ji|≤2b, make makes the balls cover T. Can anyone show me how setting the centers of the balls in such way covers the cube? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a grid of size $\epsilon$ dividing the cube. They are covering the cube by placing on each vertex of the grid a ball of radius $\epsilon$.